# How can I remove manually added page breaks?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, page-break

I added a page-break to my spreadsheet but now I want some more lines at the top of page **2**. I want to remove the page break as part of doing this.

How do I remove the existing page break (that I had added before)?

I've gone through all the menus and options and I can't find a thing. I've tried adding the new lines for page 2 in several places but they keep falling into page 1.  I want new lines at line 22 but on page 2.

Screenshot showing pagebreak I am trying to remove (blue line):

[image: page-break I am trying to remove]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

```
[Edit],[Delete Page Break]
```

This is the 5th item from the bottom

Note from Michael: You need to be on the FIRST row of page 2 for the 'delete page break - row' to NOT be grayed out!

[image]

Comment: This does not work for LibreOffice 5.1.622. There is no such menu item

Comment: I am still on 5.0.5.2 (where it still works...) and am now reluctant to upgrade to 5.1.622.

Answer (score 0):

It is available on LibreOffice 6.0.4.2 under `Sheet -> Delete Page Break -> Row or Column Break`